# Outlook 2003 removing emails from Exchange server as it syncs

Tags: microsoft-outlook, exchange, exchange-2003, cached-exchange-mode

I feel a little embarressed at having to ask this, but I'm short on time and an obvious solution evades me:

I have a user who swaps between using 2 desktop machines.  Desktop 1 has Outlook 2010 installed on it, and Desktop 2 has Outlook 2003 installed (for legacy plug-in support).
Both machines connect to our Exchange 2003 server.

Up until now, she has been able to use both machines seemlessly, but recently Desktop 2 had to be rebuilt.  On configuring Outlook 2003 for her, it began to download all of her mails and strip them from the Exchange server.  We could actively see them being downloaded to Outlook 2003 and removed from Outlook 2010's inbox, so I quickly switched Outlook 2003 to Offline mode to prevent further loss.

Both machines have Cached Exchange mode disabled (the same as before the rebuild), but regardless of whether I enable or disable it, the same issue occurs.

I've been through all the menus I can find and can't find an option related to this issue.  It's as if I'm connecting via POP3 with 'Leave a copy on the server' disabled.

Anyone have any ideas?  Thanks!

Comment: Don't be embarassed asking things, something is only simple when you know the answer. Often when you're too close or have spent too long on the problem the simple fixes can be elusive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this [here](https://getsatisfaction.com/microsoft/topics/outlook_2003_leaving_messages_on_an_exchange_server):

> Open Outlook. Go Tools, Email Accounts. Check view or change existing
>   email accounts. Click Next. Make sure the "Deliver new email to the
>   following location:" is set to "Mailbox - Your mailbox name" not a
>   personal or pst folder. This will leave all the messages on the server
>   and you will be able to view them from home computer as well

The same problem is also referenced [here](http://kb.iu.edu/data/aedh.html) with a similar fix described
Hope it helps

Comment: That's great, thanks for that!  Yeah, this would seem to be the problem...she has a 2010 local mailbox so we redirected her mail into a 2003 pst.  Wonder if there's a way to get the removed data back onto the server again?  I can only wish!  Guess I could always restore a mailbox backup to the server....

Comment: In the first link there's a comment that says: 















nightskyproject 1 year ago 


Well, what worked for me was selecting all the emails that were saved in my Personal Folder and drag them to the Mailbox - UserName with a mouse.

 Easy as that. Beautifully strange simplicity for Microsoft...

 Main thing is to point to where to save the emails...

Comment: Yep, that totally worked.  Actioned this week and it was easy as pie.  Thanks for all your help Joe.

Comment: Glad it helped, hopefully it will help others too.